# PC not booting from install image DVD

Tags: boot, system-installation, lubuntu, dvd

I have an old pc that I'm trying to install Lubuntu on. I downloaded the torrent (really small file) and the 700+MB file. The larger file shows up as a WinRAR, although it ends with .iso. I inserted a blank DVD into the laptop with the large .iso file. An option showed up to use the DVD as either a Flash Drive or a CD/DVD. I tried to burn with the CD/DVD option and I set the bios of the other PC to start first from a CD (no DVD option), although this didn't work as the PC just booted into Windows as per usual. I then tried to burn with the flash drive option. I am using Windows 10 and when I right-click on the file, there is no option to 'Burn'. The PC just boots into Windows with no sign it booting to the Lubuntu installer. Any help as to make the PC boot to the install process would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Are you sure your CD drive supports DVD?

Comment: @Akiva If I try to boot from a USB, can I format the USB and use it normally afterwards?

Comment: Yep. But just be careful not to replace the filesystem that comes on the flash drive. I have destroyed a flashdrive doing that before, replacing NTFS with ext4.

Comment: @Akiva The flash drive is showing up as a Winrar file, but ends in iso. Will that be ok?

Comment: Yep; If you are speaking of the Icon; the icon represents an archive, and an ISO is an archive.

You should do a Checksum though no matter what, to verify the image is correct.

Comment: What processor do you have on this old machine?

Comment: @Akiva I'm not sure

Comment: @Akiva How do I do a Checksum?

Comment: Right Click My Computer, and go to "Properties" -- That should tell you what processor you have. 
Don't worry about the checksum too much. Its just percautionary, especially if you are using a dvd, but not so much with flash.